# Python で reverse を使わずにリストを逆にする方法

Tags: python

Python で `reverse` を使わずにリストを逆にする方法を教えてください。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が出てきますのでお好みで。[Python でリストを反転する](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python/python-reverse-a-list/), [Pythonでリストや文字列を逆順に並べ替え（reverse, reversed）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-reverse-reversed/), [Pythonのリストを逆順に並び替る方法｜reverse(), reversed(), スライス](https://www.headboost.jp/python-list-random-sort/), [Python リストの逆順](https://qiita.com/take333/items/b61e43c68751260689a6), [［解決！Python］リスト（配列）をソートしたり、逆順にしたりするには（sort／reverseメソッド、sorted／reversed関数）](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/2012/22/news022.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えばループを使うとか。

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listB = []
length = len(listA)
for i in range(length):
    listB.append(listA[length - 1 - i])

print(listB)
```

ループの中で逆順でリストの要素にアクセスしています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

```py
>>> lst = [*range(10)]
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます